# Función con Vanilla JS se ejecuta al cargar la página

Tags: javascript, html5

Bien, el problema es el siguiente:
Pasa que al momento de cargar la página ejecuta automáticamente (sin dar click al botón)la función que debería ejecutar el evento "submit".

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById;
formulario.addEventListener("submit", llamar());

function llamar() {
  alert("Presionado");
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="formulario">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente, tienes que dar un `id` al formulario, e indicarlo en el selector, pues aquí realmente no estás seleccionado nada ([ver la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)):

```
var formulario = document.getElementById;
```

Luego, al poner el código así:

```
formulario.addEventListener("submit", llamar());
```

En vez de asignar la función al listener, lo que haces es que llamas a la función. Debes quitarle los paréntesis `()`

Otra cosa, si quieres evitar que la página se recargue cuando envíes el formulario (por ejemplo en el caso de Ajax), pásale el evento a `llamar` y ejecuta dentro de ella `preventDefault()`. Si quieres que se recargue le quitas esa línea.

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById("miForm");
formulario.addEventListener("submit", llamar);

function llamar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("Presionado");
}
```

```html
<form action="" name="formulario" id="miForm">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```